# Reverse Zone File in Bind - NXDOMAIN (nslookup ip address)

Tags: linux, apache, centos, bind, nameservers

I followed a few tutorials and setup web hosting and nameservers for my domain name: etechnical.com.

**Nameservers**: ns1.etechnical.com and ns2.etechnical.com

I configured apache (httpd.conf) and bind (named.conf).

**The domain/hosting resolves fine.** (i.e. etechnical.com resolves to a test page)

nslookup etechnical.com - appears to be fine.

**The problem**

nslookup 192.249.58.225 - shows a NXDOMAIN error--it can't find the domain associated with the ip address.

This tells me I have a problem with my reverse zone file?

Here is my configuration files:

**named.conf file:**

```
options {
   directory "/var/named";
   dump-file "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
   statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
 // query-source address * port 53;
};

 controls {
       inet 127.0.0.1 port 953
               allow { 127.0.0.1; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
 };


zone "etechnical.com" IN {
   type master;
   file "/var/named/etechnical.com";
   allow-update { none; };
};

zone "58.249.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
   type master;
   file "/var/named/58.249.192.rev";
   allow-update { none; };
};

include "/etc/rndc.key";
```

**/var/named/etechnical.com zone file:**

```
; Authoritative data for etechnical.com
$TTL 14400
@      IN      SOA     ns1.etechnical.com. root.ns.etechnical.com. (
                2006071701      ; serial, todays date+todays
                14400           ; refresh, seconds
                7200            ; retry, seconds
                3600000         ; expire, seconds
                86400 )         ; minimum, seconds
        IN      NS      ns1.etechnical.com.
        IN      NS      ns2.etechnical.com.
        IN      A       192.249.58.225
*       IN      A       192.249.58.225
ns      IN      A       192.249.58.225
mail    IN      CNAME   etechnical.com.
ftp     IN      CNAME   etechnical.com.
ns2     IN      A       192.249.58.225
```

**58.249.192.rev - reverse zone map or file  (problem here??):**

```
$TTL    86400
@                 IN SOA          ns1.etechnical.com. root.ns.etechnical.com. (
100     ; serial
1H      ; refresh
1M      ; retry
1W      ; expiry
1D)     ; minimum
@                IN NS            ns1.etechnical.com.
1                 IN PTR          etechnical.com.
```

**resolv.conf file**

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1  //I added this line?
nameserver 8.8.8.8  //already here...
nameserver 8.8.4.4  //already here...
```

After making changes, I generally a) restart bind and b) rndc reload

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already have this figured out. For the record, in your reverse zone file you had only the entry for the IP ending in 1 and you needed an entry for the 225 as well, according to your example in the question:

```
$TTL    86400
@                 IN SOA          ns1.etechnical.com. root.ns.etechnical.com. (
100     ; serial
1H      ; refresh
1M      ; retry
1W      ; expiry
1D)     ; minimum
@                IN NS            ns1.etechnical.com.
1                 IN PTR          etechnical.com.
255               IN PTR          etechical.com.
```